# How to avoid scanning certain directory via php

Tags: php

I have **6** folders but I only want to scan **4**. here is the structural folder arrangement.

The **main_folder** contains three sub-folder **(second_folder, third_folder and Telex_folder)** 
while the **third_folder** contains a sub-folder **(cosmetic_folder and provision_folder)** and so on.

Currently with the code below, I can scan all the files in all **directories** and all **sub-directories** and its working great as per
code below.

```
function outputFiles1($path){
    // Check directory exists or not
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        // Search the files in this directory
        $files = glob($path ."/*");
        if(count($files) > 0){
            // Loop through retuned array
            foreach($files as $file){
                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    echo basename($file) ."<br>";
                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    // Recursively call the function if directories found
                    outputFiles1("$file");
                }
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: No such file found in the directory.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}

// Call the function
outputFiles1("C:/xampp/htdocs/first_main_folder");
```

Now I want to scan all directories while leaving **cosmetic_folder and **provision_folder** directory un-scanned.

Please how do I avoid scanning **(cosmetic_folder and provision_folder)** sub-directories while scanning is going on.

Thanks

```
first_Main_folder
test.png
data.php
check.gif


    second_folder
    tony.jpg
    mark.gif
    action.php

    third_folder
    index.php
    post.php
    sender.php
    han.gif

        cosmetic_folder
            cosmetic1.csv
            cosmetic2.csv

        provision_folder
            prov1.xml
            prov2.pdf

    telex_folder
    contact1.csv
    conctact.pdf
```

Comment: Why not just add a condition to test for those directory names in an `if` statement and `continue` if it matches?

Comment: thanks @ehymel you save my time

Answer (score 0):

```
function outputFiles1($path, $depth= 0){
    if ($depth > 1) {
        break;
        //or do what you want then ;)
    }
    // Check directory exists or not
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        // Search the files in this directory
        $files = glob($path ."/*");
        if(count($files) > 0){
            // Loop through retuned array
            foreach($files as $file){
                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    echo basename($file) ."<br>";
                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    // Recursively call the function if directories found
                    outputFiles1("$file", $depth+1);
                }
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: No such file found in the directory.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}

// Call the function
outputFiles1("C:/xampp/htdocs/first_main_folder");
```

Answer (score 0):

The scanning was resolved using 
 [substr-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) which was passed within if statement.

```
  if( ($file != '*') && (substr( $file , -6 ) != 'cosmetic_folder') && (substr( $file , -6 ) != 'provision_folder') ){


//foreach continue.....
}
```

hence resolved as per code below

```
function outputFiles1($path){
    // Check directory exists or not
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        // Search the files in this directory
        $files = glob($path ."/*");
        if(count($files) > 0){
            // Loop through retuned array
            foreach($files as $file){

  if( ($file != '*') && (substr( $file , -6 ) != 'cosmetic_folder') && (substr( $file , -6 ) != 'provision_folder') ){
                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    echo "$file"  . "<br>";
                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    // Recursively call the function if directories found
                    outputFiles1("$file");
                }
}
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: No such file found in the directory.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}
```